# Unhandled exception: Exception: Cannot find the executable for `where`

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I'm installing Flutter to develop apps on Windows 10. I accidentally deleted the environment variable, but I recovered its path through the terminal with the echo %PATH% command. After that, I entered the corresponding path to the \bin folder in the same Path environment variable. Now, a new problem appeared when typing the `futtler´ command in the terminal:

```
Unhandled exception:
Exception: Cannot find the executable for `where`. This can happen if the System32 folder (e.g. C:\Windows\System32 ) is removed from the PATH environment variable. Ensure that this is present and then try again after restarting the terminal and/or IDE.
#0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
#1      _WindowsUtils._which (package:flutter_tools/src/base/os.dart:488:7)
#2      OperatingSystemUtils.whichAll (package:flutter_tools/src/base/os.dart:101:43)
#3      AndroidSdk.locateAndroidSdk.findAndroidHomeDir (package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_sdk.dart:124:46)
#4      AndroidSdk.locateAndroidSdk (package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_sdk.dart:148:36)
#5      AppContext._generateIfNecessary.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:104:42)
#6      _LinkedHashMapMixin.putIfAbsent (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:535:23)
#7      AppContext._generateIfNecessary (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:92:20)
#8      AppContext.get (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:121:32)
#9      androidSdk (package:flutter_tools/src/globals.dart:66:39)
#10     generateCommands (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:174:25)
#11     main.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:93:11)
#12     run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:52:13)
<asynchronous suspension>
#13     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#14     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:91:3)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

I tried to search the internet for the solution to the problem, but it is too specific and I couldn't find anything that would help me. I don't know if it has to do with the Path environment variable, because I recreated it with the command ´echo %PATH%.´ What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add `C:\Windows\System32` in your PATH variable.